# A Fibonacci like Stochastic process

Tags: sequences-and-series, random-variables, fibonacci-numbers, characteristic-functions

Let $X_0, X_1$ and $\{a_n,n\geq0\}$ are i.i.d. $\sim $Bernoulli$(1/2)$ taking values in $\{0,2\}$. Let us define $X_n$ for $n>1$ as below$$X_{n+1}=a_nX_n+a_{n-1}X_{n-1},\ n\geq1 $$  Then it follows that $\{\mathbb{E}[X_n]\}$ is a Fibonacci sequence. But I could infer nothing for either $\mathbb{E}[X_{n}^k]$ for $k>1$ or for the characteristic function of $X_n$, $n>1$. Any idea?

**Edit:** I forgot to mention my progress. Here is what I could do:

$$\mathbb{E}(e^{tX_{n+1}})=\mathbb{E}(e^{ta_{n}X_n})\mathbb{E}(e^{ta_{n-1}X_{n-1}})$$ Now, $$\mathbb{E}(e^{ta_{n}X_n})=\frac{1}{2}\left(\mathbb{E}(e^{2tX_n})+1\right)$$ Denoting $\mathbb{E}(e^{tX_n})=:m_n(t)$, we get the recurrence, $$m_{n+1}(t)=\frac{1}{4}(1+m_n(2t))(1+m_{n-1}(2t))$$

Comment: Is there no solution to this problem?

Comment: Is the sequence $(a_n)$ independent?

Comment: Yes, @DavideGiraudo, $a_n\perp X_n$, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: You might as well set $X_0=0$, $X_1=1$ (or $X_1=1$, $X_2=1$); the first few $X_n$ will still get randomized suitably but it might make the analysis marginally easier.

Comment: Yes, @StevenStadnicki, that is possible, but can it facilitate the analysis anymore than what I have already done?

Comment: Not hugely, like I said, but it does remove one small variable from the works.  I think the characteristic function here is inevitably going to be a big mess; you may be able to get some asymptotics, but not much more than that.

Comment: Yes, that is why I could not make any progress after that.